# Is this a constrained optimization?

Tags: optimization, terminology

Consider a minimization with regard to $\theta$:

$Q(\theta) = [y-f(\theta)]'[y-f(\theta)]$ $\quad$  (1)

where $y,(m \times 1)$ is a data vector, $\theta=(\theta_1, \theta_2)'$ is a $p×1$ vector with $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ being $p_1 \times 1$ and $p_2 \times 1$, respectively.

In my case, from the first-order condition associated with (1), i.e., $\partial Q(\theta)/\partial \theta = 0$, I have the following (not closed form) solution for $\theta_2$:

$\theta_2 = h(\theta)$ $\quad$ (2)

where $h(\theta)$ is a known function.

If I rewrite the minimization problem as follows

$\min Q(\theta)$ with subject to $\theta_2 = h(\theta)$ $\quad$,

I'm wondering if this becomes a constrained optimization problem since the restriction (2) is derived from the optimization problem (1) itself.

In terms of computation, minimizing (1) with or without a restriction (2) yield very different results.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is unconstrained.  When you include the optimality condition (2) as an explicit constraint, the new problem is constrained.  If (2) holds "without loss of optimality," you should get the same optimal objective value.

Comment: Many thanks! Then, the values of $\theta$ that minimize $Q(\theta)$ should be identical regardless of whether the constraint (2) is imposed or not. So, if two are different, that should be a numerical issue, right?

Comment: There might be multiple optimal $\theta$, but you should get the same minimum value for $Q(\theta)$.